i have a problem when i import unidecode in python script (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unidecode' )
I installed the unidecode module through pip, version 3.10.6 of python is configured although I have version 3.12 and the address of the interpreter has already changed but version 3.10 of anaconda is still maintained, I would appreciate if someone can help me solve it Why does the script not find the unidecode module, I work in vscode studio on Windows 10 (I don't know if this is relevant information) I'll stay tuned, thank you.
pip install Unidecode
from unidecode import unidecode 
from faker import Faker 
from faker.providers import DynamicProvider 
from faker.providers import date_time 
from datetime import datetime 
import random 
import json     

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unidecode'
I understand that the python interpreter does not have access to the location of the module (unidecode). I have seen that in previous versions of python they added the path in sys.path but I don't know if it works in this version and I think that the path they added is from a Linux system and I am working on Windows, so I don't know what modification I should make.
i tried with this code -->
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts\unidecode.exe")

import sys
import os

os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))

SCRIPT_DIR = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts\unidecode.exe"

but don't fix it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note with Windows, your paths need to be escaped.. i.e. SCRIPT_DIR = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\..."  or use SCRIPT_DIR = r"C:\Users\..."
